# Recommended SOLR installer with Sitecore 8.1 (Update 1)

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am working on sitecore 8.1 (Update 1), i want to know what is the recommended version for SOLR installer with Sitecore there is two version from bitnami website :

1. **Apache Solr 5.5.0-0**
2. **Apache Solr 4.10.3-0**

https://bitnami.com/stack/solr/installer

last time I installed Apache Solr 5.5.0-0 (latest version), and I had alot of issues with Siteocre 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for Solr 4.10.x. You will save a lot of troubles. And there is not much new in Solr 5.x that would be beneficial for Sitecore application.

I'm not sure about bitnami installers, but from what I know, one of the most popular Solr version for Sitecore is **Solr 4.10.4**. You can download it from http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/

Comment: Bitnami SOLR is great for local development, since it also installs all the required components such as Tomcat, but it is not Production ready. SOLR 5 does not have this requirement so Bitnami does not add much advatnage.

Comment: I would also add that in production, put SOLR on Linux - don't run it on Windows. Its always been troublesome for us when we do that.

Comment: That's interesting @RichardSeal . We run Solr on tomcat on Windows without any issues.